# Unwanted lines in ggmap

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to get a simple map of Europe in ggmap, but I'm encountering different problems with different projections. This code generates the right map but with an unwanted vertical line a zero degree longitude. Using 'mercator' projection cuts off half the world at zero degrees!

What to do?

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(map)
library(mapdata)
world.wire <- map_data("world2") 
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = world.wire, aes(x=long, y = lat, group =   group), color="white", fill="grey40") + 
coord_map(projection = "stereographic", ylim =c(30,60), xlim=c(-20,20))
```

Comment: is there a reason why you don't use `world` instead of `world2`?

Comment: Now that's a simple solution to both issues! I had misremembered that world2 was more recent, but it's just a different orientation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question was solved by @beetroot using `world.wire <- map_data("world")` (see comments)